# Understanding the recombination and decoupling periods in the early universe

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmic-microwave-background

I have a couple of questions about the recombination and photon decoupling. The problem is I have 2 references that give different time scales for these two periods.

For recombination:

In Roos, it's defined as

$$\chi = \frac {n_e}  {n_{bar}} = 0.1$$

while in Barbara $$\chi = 0.5$$

I guess theres not a general convention for the $\chi$ value ?

Meanwhile, decoupling happened when $\Gamma < H$.  So at this point, they also give different time scales

Roos gives us redshift values for these periods as

$z_{rec} = 1100$, $z_{LSS}=1089$, $z_{dec}=890$

and Barbara

$z_{rec} = 1380$, $z_{LSS}=1090$, $z_{dec}=1090$

Which one is correct?  And why? Is it because they have different $\chi$ values ?

If Roos then why is there is so much difference between  $z_{LSS}$ and  $z_{dec}$?

I know that $z_{LSS}$ is not a single value it has some sort of a range but still, there's a huge difference between 2 values.

Also, I think that when the decoupling happens we should expect to see LSS ( Last scattering surface) so in my opinion $z_{dec} \approx z_{LSS}$.

Comment: I think you need to give all the details. These calculations depend on what physics is included, as well as on the definitions of the terms, and very mildly on the assumed cosmological parameters.

Comment: @RobJeffries Hmm They are kind of long. Roos does not go much into the details of the calculations. And For barbara I can reference the page numbers  (2 nd Edition Section 8.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have these textbooks to hand, so don't know (apart from the ionisation fraction that your question points out) what differences there are in the physics behind these calculations (e.g. see https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9909275) the definitions of the terms or differences in the assumed cosmological parameters.

The largest figure in your list looks like what you get from assuming $\chi=0.5$ and a simple equilibrium model with the Saha equation. More complex (numerical) calculations of the last scattering surface, where the integrated optical depth to electron scattering is 1, usually give a lower value of redshift - so I would suggest that both sources are quoting the results of those calculations, but Roos chooses $\chi=0.1$, because the simple Saha treatment gives a result that is similar to the more complex calculation of the LSS.

The decoupling epoch is where the time between scatterings, which depends on the ionisation fraction, becomes larger than the Hubble time. The exact answer will depend on the form of $\chi(z)$, which in turn depends on the detailed physics in the calculation and (slightly) on the cosmological parameters.

I don't think $z_{\rm dec}$ and $z_{\rm LSS}$ are necessarily the same thing. The former depends on the conditions at one epoch, while the latter depends on the integral of conditions over all redshifts back to an earlier epoch.

Comment: There are pdff versions but they do go  much mention in detail.  **"I don't think zdec and zLSS are necessarily the same thing. The former depends on the conditions at one epoch, while the latter depends on the integral of conditions over all redshifts back to an earlier epoch."**                                                                                          
              It seems somewhat strange .. I mean decoupling means that electrons do not scatter anymore so at near those periods we should see LSS. I can understand if the diffference was $\approx 10-20$z but its like $200z$.

Comment: Recombination is different due to $X$ as you said. And that makes sense.

Comment: @Reign I think you are right. I offer no explanation for the 890 figure. It almost looks like a typo.

Comment: Thats really interesting. Maybe I send a mail to him